# Htaccess rewrite index with trailing slash or without

Tags: .htaccess

I am currently having a problem with my index url rewrite in my .htaccess file, I know if I use

```
RewriteRule ^profile/([^/]*)/?$ /profile.php?x=$1 [L]
```

I would be able to use www.example.com/profile/get or www.example.com/profile/get/ (with or without trailing slash)

But I would like www.example.com/get what I have so far is

```
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)\/$ /index.php?x=$1 [L]
```

But if I put a ? before the $ it errors any answers welcome

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Making the trailing slash optional will lead to an infinite loop, since `[^/]*` will match anything that doesn't include a `/`, ie it would also match `index.php?x=get`

You can avoid this by making the rule [apply conditionally](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritecond), for example by testing the reqeust URI:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/index\.php.*
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)\/?$ /index.php?x=$1 [L]
```

That way the rule can only apply in case the request URI doesn't start with `/index.php`